# Which algorithm is best to categorize forum questions?

Tags: text-mining

I want to categorize users based on the question they post in forums like wordpress, drupal etc. I am stuck at initial step to proceed. Please help me out !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create, for every user, a bag of words built from every question they posted.

Then you can start, for instance, by applying [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation), where every user is a mixture of topics.

Comment: Is there any good algorithm to filter unwanted words and select the relevant words only to create bag of words. Any related open tools to use as my data are in csv format.

Comment: There are lists of "stop words" that you should use. They are available in almost, if not all, language processing library. Check the `nltk` library for python, for instance.